# Kubernetes can't access pod in multi worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I was following a tutorial on youtube and the guy said that if you deploy your application in a multi-cluster setup and if your service is of type NodePort, you don't have to worry from where your pod gets scheduled. You can access it with different node IP address like

`worker1IP:servicePort` or `worker2IP:servicePort` or `workerNIP:servicePort`

But I tried just now and this is not the case, I can only access the pod on the node from where it is scheduled and deployed. Is it correct behavior?

```
kubectl version --short 
> Client Version: v1.18.5 
> Server Version: v1.18.5
```

**kubectl get pods -n kube-system**

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-66bff467f8-6pt8s                0/1     Running            288        7d22h
coredns-66bff467f8-t26x4                0/1     Running            288        7d22h
etcd-redhat-master                      1/1     Running            16         7d22h
kube-apiserver-redhat-master            1/1     Running            17         7d22h
kube-controller-manager-redhat-master   1/1     Running            19         7d22h
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-9mh6k             1/1     Running            16         5d22h
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-g2k5c             1/1     Running            16         5d22h
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-rnvgb             1/1     Running            14         5d22h
kube-proxy-gf8zk                        1/1     Running            16         7d22h
kube-proxy-wt7cp                        1/1     Running            9          7d22h
kube-proxy-zbw4b                        1/1     Running            9          7d22h
kube-scheduler-redhat-master            1/1     Running            18         7d22h
weave-net-6jjd8                         2/2     Running            34         7d22h
weave-net-ssqbz                         1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   296        7d22h
weave-net-ts2tj                         2/2     Running            34         7d22h




[root@redhat-master deployments]# kubectl logs weave-net-ssqbz -c weave -n kube-system
DEBU: 2020/07/05 07:28:04.661866 [kube-peers] Checking peer "b6:01:79:66:7d:d3" against list &{[{e6:c9:b2:5f:82:d1 redhat-master} {b2:29:9a:5b:89:e9 redhat-console-1} {e2:95:07:c8:a0:90 redhat-console-2}]}
Peer not in list; removing persisted data
INFO: 2020/07/05 07:28:04.924399 Command line options: map[conn-limit:200 datapath:datapath db-prefix:/weavedb/weave-net docker-api: expect-npc:true host-root:/host http-addr:127.0.0.1:6784 ipalloc-init:consensus=2 ipalloc-range:10.32.0.0/12 metrics-addr:0.0.0.0:6782 name:b6:01:79:66:7d:d3 nickname:redhat-master no-dns:true port:6783]
INFO: 2020/07/05 07:28:04.924448 weave  2.6.5
FATA: 2020/07/05 07:28:04.938587 Existing bridge type "bridge" is different than requested "bridged_fastdp". Please do 'weave reset' and try again
```

**Update:**
So basically the issue is because iptables is deprecated in rhel8. But After downgrading my OS to rhel7. I can access the nodeport only on the node it is deployed.

Comment: where is the Kubernetes cluster deployed? Public cloud or on Prem? Do you have security group or firewalls?

Comment: it's on prem cluster setup running in kubeadm. How to validate the security group and firewall? if I changed the replicas to 4 and it's distributed evenly on my 2 worker nodes I'm able to access both nodes.

Comment: are you able to ping one node from other node? or telnet from one node to other node on the nodeport?

Comment: yes on all nodes I can ping each other

Comment: what cni plugin you chose? Can you check logs of the cni plugins pod?

Comment: how to know? and what command to exec?

Comment: share output of kubectl get pods -n kube-system

Comment: updated on my post

Comment: You have 3 nodes. and it does not work from one of the node? Add output of kubectl logs weave-net-ssqbz -n kube-system

Comment: error: a container name must be specified for pod weave-net-ssqbz, choose one of: [weave weave-npc]

Comment: add output of kubectl logs weave-net-ssqbz -c weave -n kube-system and kubectl logs weave-net-ssqbz -c weave-npc -n kube-system

Comment: added in the log, for the second one the result is huge, can't copy here

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu can you please confirm that my scenario is not valid and pod should be accessible in any worker node IP ?

Comment: your cluster does not seem so healthy. The CoreDNS pods are restarting over and over again and one of yours is in CrashLoopBackOff...

Comment: Before I was facing some issues in my /etc/resolvr where I suddenly losing network connection. Btw this setup is in VMs

Comment: Yes it should be accessible..but weave makes that possible..one of your weave pod is not running

Comment: I managed to make the failing weave pod run, but the issue is still there.

Comment: Is there any reason why did you deployed wave and flannel? Did you try to disable SELinux and setup firewall rules as described [here](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-1-7-centos7-rhel7/)?

Comment: @acid_fuji good point, actually I realized it and already removed it before you mentioned it here. Now I tried to reset the cluster install calico. All kube-system pods including the calico pods are started properly and running. But this time I can't access it in any nodes :(

Comment: How did you performed the reset? with Kubeadm reset? Have you check the steps that I provided in the URL?

Comment: yes I did the the very first time, should i do it every after kubeadm reset?

Comment: One time is enough. Can you share the tutorial link that you followed? Can you please update the question with minimal steps need to reproduce this? What OS are you using along with version, vm software and version , Calico version, pod CIDR,etc. Can you also update question with `kubectl get nodes -owide` command.

Comment: @acid_fuji please see here, I revised the question https://serverfault.com/questions/1024350/kubernetes-calico-service-accessible-only-from-where-the-pod-is-deployed